# pygame in conda environment

Tags: python, pygame, anaconda, conda

I switched to anaconda as it provides most of the library for Data Analysis, tools like Ipython, spyder IDE, Jupyter Notebook in one install. It was Hassle free!

But I am having problem with installing pygame. I've tried,

```
conda install -c cogsci pygame
conda install -c cogsci pygame=1.9.2a0
```

both of the time i got similar result. like this,

```
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - pygame=1.9.2a0 -> python=2.7
  - python=3.6
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.
```

I am well aware that `conda install -c tlatorre pygame` is only for linux. So, if anyone know where the library has been moved or how to install this in conda environment, help me!

Comment: have you tried using `pip install pygame`?

Answer (score 3):

The error says that while you have python 3.6 installed in your environment while the `cogsci` channel has `pygame` that is dependent on python 2.7. The solution is either to move to the older version of python or to try to install pygame either from source (see [Pygame site](https://www.pygame.org) for details) or from another channel. The list of channels with `pygame` package can be found with the command

```
anaconda search pygame
```

You will be returned a list of channels, look for your platform. Note that you might need to install anaconda command line client with

```
conda install anaconda-client
```

Comment: you could always use pip

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't agree to use pip __always__ . Mixing conda and pip have often had me confused when it comes to keeping track of installed packages. Is it just me, am I missing something clear solution for this?

Comment: I didn't mean you should *always* use pip, that is an idiomomatic way of saying *you could use pip*. Anyway, I've never had that problem. `conda` is designed to work alongside `pip`. `conda list` even provides a list of all packages installed in the current environment, and delineates which ones come from `pip`...